# Check if Postgres jsonb contains one of the values

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I need to check if jsonb field that can be an array or just string.
Simple data that I have:

```
INSERT INTO users (jsonb) VALUES
('{"name":"Henry", "favoritefood_1":["eggs","apples"]}'),
('{"name":"Herald","favoritefood_1":["apples","potatoes"]}'),
('{"name":"Helen", "favoritefood_1":"apples"}');
```

How should I find users that love apples and eggs? I tried many queries and the last of them is:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE CASE
WHEN jsonb_typeof((jsonb->>'favoritefood_1')::jsonb) = 'array'
THEN jsonb_array_elements((jsonb->>'favoritefood_1')::jsonb) IN ('apples', 'eggs')
ELSE (jsonb->>'favoritefood_1')::jsonb IN ('apples', 'eggs') END
```

Can anybody help me with that, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where jsonb -> 'favoritefood_1' ?| array['apples', 'eggs']
```

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer this formulation over the one @GMB contributed a couple of days ago?

Comment: I have different amount of values to search by. So it is more easy to create such type of query instead @GMB contributed.

Comment: FYI. `?& array['apples', 'eggs']` for both values to be satisfied. More: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE

Answer (score 3):

Just `?` should work:

```
where jsonb -> 'favoritefood_1' ? 'apples'
```

Comment: I was suggesting an `or` with `@>` but this is way better.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: thanks. I actually tested it before posting, I wasn't sure Postgres was that smart. +1 for Postgres, the more I use it the more I like it.

Comment: I have cases when I need to find user that likes apples or eggs

Comment: @psmagin: `where jsonb -> 'favoritefood_1' ? 'apples' or jsonb -> 'favoritefood_1' ? 'eggs'`